# php file renaming and folder renaming

Tags: php, html, forms, file-upload, rename

i used the following code to create new folder with input text name and used renaming for uploading file

```
$dir = $file_path .= $input .'/';
$file_path = "img/";
$input = $_POST['caption']; // this is the new folder you'll create
$file_path .= $input . '/';
if (!file_exists($file_path)) {
mkdir($file_path);
}
chmod($file_path, 0777);

$file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {
    echo "success";
} else{
    echo "fail";
}

$ran = rand (1.1,1);
$ran2 = $ran.".";
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file1"]["name"]));
if ((($_FILES["file1"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file1"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file1"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file1"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file1"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file1"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["file1"]["size"] < 2000000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
{
if ($_FILES["file1"]["error"] > 0)
{
echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file1"]["error"] . "<br>";
}
else
{
echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file1"]["name"] . "<br>";
echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file1"]["type"] . "<br>";
echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file1"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file1"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

  if (file_exists("$dir" . $_FILES["file1"]["name"]))
  {
  echo $_FILES["file1"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
  }
  else
  {
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file1"]["tmp_name"], "$dir" . $ran2 . $extension);
  echo "Stored in: " . "$dir" . $_FILES["file1"]["name"];
  }
  }
  }
else
{
echo "Invalid file or service down";
echo "It must be an image to be uploaded.";
}
```

but when i run in hosting i get the following error i got the above codes from your own website i have combined two codes as single code file creating a folder and renaming file

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(/1.png) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/a3629462/public_html/1.php on line 49
```

Comment: I don't know about the solution, but I do have a suggestion.

Replace
    (($_FILES["file1"]["type"] == "image/gif")
    || ($_FILES["file1"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
    || ($_FILES["file1"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
    || ($_FILES["file1"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
    || ($_FILES["file1"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
    || ($_FILES["file1"]["type"] == "image/png"))
with
in_array($_FILES['file1']['type'], array("image/gif","image/jpeg","image/jpg","image/pjpeg","image/x-png","image/png")

Comment: `$input` is blank (maybe NULL), your script send file to "root", this is wrong, use absolute paths, which folder you want to send the file? What value should have the variable `$input`?

Comment: when run a new folder is created but the file is not moved to server

Comment: Wchich line is line 49? What's the output of echo? Do you try to upload 2 files at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really hard to say what you are doing. For example lines:

```
$dir = $file_path .= $input .'/';
$file_path = "img/";
$input = $_POST['caption']; // this is the new folder you'll create
$file_path .= $input . '/';
```

don't seem too obvious. You set `$dir` as `$file_path` appended with some input or it is just an error?

Another thing:

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {
    echo "success";
} else{
    echo "fail";
}
```

So after those lines it's hard to say what happened, because you have only `$file_path` without any file name. I always rather use file name when using `move_uploaded_file`

Another thing - it seems you try to upload 2 files. Why you do any checks just for the second file and not for the first one? Or maybe that's mistake and you try to upload only one file? In that case everything might me wrong with your code.

Another error is:

```
rand (1.1,1);
```

For `rand()` you should only pass integers not floats and this one will return always `1` as far as I see.

It's also quite possible that `$dir` directory does not exist because you never tried to create one in your code. In fact it seems that `$dir` is `/` is empty string so you try to create file in `/` (root server directory) what of course is not allowed because you should create it in your user/domain directory.

I would advise you to write the whole code again. There are plenty of possible errors.